# Type 'String' has no call signatures

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

I have no idea what the hell is wrong with this and why TS is complaining.  I must be missing something I don't know about TS:

**App.js**

```
function fullName(firstName: string, lastName: string): string {
  return `${firstName} ${lastName}`;
}

function toUser(view: any, body: any, emailAddress: any) {
  const fullName: string = fullName(firstName, lastName);
  ...
}
```

**Errors:**

```
 Type 'String' has no call signatures.

    86  const fullName: string = fullName(firstName, lastName);

TS2448: Block-scoped variable 'fullName' used before its declaration.

    86  const fullName: string = fullName(firstName, lastName);

const fullName: string = fullName(firstName, lastName);
                  ~~~~~~~~
        'fullName' is declared here.

error TS2454: Variable 'fullName' is used before being assigned.

    86  const fullName: string = fullName(firstName, lastName);
```

[image]

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: the function fullName returns a string.  I'm just trying to get this damn code to compile without TS bitching here.  The errors make absolutely no sense to me.  The functions look fine to me.

Comment: The error message says `String`. In your code you are using `string`. That are two different types. Is this your actual code? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I didn't downvote but have you read the error messages? _"Block-scoped variable 'fullName' used before its declaration."_, _"'fullName' is declared here."_, _"Variable 'fullName' is used before being assigned."_

Comment: of course I read them and it just was not obvious.  I was thinking wtf my function is defined before I used it.  Those errors were not obvious to the fact that I was naming 3 things the same, as again I thought the scopes were diff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function and the variable have the same name. You are shadowing the function.

Comment: hmm I figured the const name was out of scope of the function so it would be ok..